# How Do I Use the "Backup Database" Statement to Overwrite an Existing Database Backup?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to write a database backup statement that will overwrite the existing backup but I'm not having any luck. I've tried various combinations of the INIT, FORMAT, and RETAINDAYS =x clauses but the backup seems to always append to the existing file instead of overwriting/recreating it.

What is the correct statement to use to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use WITH INIT provided that the name of the backup that you are taking matches the name within the backup.

Comment: That did it. I tried the INIT clause before and it didn't seem to be working but after trying it again, everything looks OK. Thanks much.

Comment: no problem, happy to help.